# Choose 5 cards from a standard deck of 52. What is the chance we will have 2 face cards...

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Choose 5 cards from a standard deck of 52. What is the chance we will have 2 face cards, 2 cards with value smaller than 6 and 1 card with value between 6 and 10 ?

Please help! Not sure how to attack this problem...

Comment: Pick which two face cards are in the hand.  Pick which two cards are of value smaller than six.  Pick which one card is between 6 and 10.  Apply multiplication principle and divide by the number of five card hands that exist.  Profit.

Comment: @Joffan If it was lauren that asked, I'd justify that with a full answer.  You clearly already know what I'm talking about and don't need me to explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the card counts in each of your categories, and pick the requisite number from each category. See [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) for the calculation of choosing (say) 2 from 20, written $\binom{20}{2}$. Since each of these three choice calculations applies regardless of the choice made in other categories, you multiply them up. Then you just need divide by the "choose 5 from 52" $\binom{52}{5}$ overall possible hands to get the probability.

Comment: I ended up get (12 2)*(20 2)*(20 1) all divided by (52 5) which gave me a probability of .0609?

Comment: @laurenq should be $250800/2598960 \approx 0.0965$

Comment: okay i see where i went wrong. Thank you